# Json file as data provider in TestNG

Tags: java, json, selenium, testng, dataprovider

Give below is my JSON structure:
I want to write a method in Java that should take only SuperParent as input parameter and return "Registration Data" and "Registration Data1" along with their child elements as TestNG dataprovider object.

```
"SuperParent":
{
    "Registration Data" : 
        {
            "FirstName"   : "Aditya Kumar",
            "LastName"    : "Roy",
            "Phone"       : "7589698874",
            "Email"       : "aditya@test.com"
        },
    "Registration Data1" :
        {
            "FirstName"   : "Preety",
            "LastName"    : "Kakkar",
            "Phone"       : "2225556669",
            "Email"       : "preety@test.com"
        }
  }
```

I have written below code but its throwing Dataprovider mismatch exception

```
public static Object[][] getTest(String regionName) 
{ 
    JsonParser jsonParser =  new JsonParser();
    JsonObject jsonObj = jsonParser.parse(new FileReader(JSONpath)).getAsJsonObject();
    JsonObject region =jsonObj.getAsJsonObject(regionName);
    Object[][] returnData = new Object[100][region.size()];
    int j = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : region.getAsJsonObject().entrySet()) 
    {

        returnData[0][j] = (region.toString());
        j++;   
   }
    return returnData;
}

    FAILED: userRegistration
org.testng.internal.reflect.MethodMatcherException: 
Data provider mismatch
Method: userRegistration([Parameter{index=0, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=1, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=2, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=3, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}])
Arguments: [(java.lang.String) {FirstName:Aditya Kumar,LastName:Roy,Phone:7589698874,Email:aditya@test.com},(java.lang.String) {FirstName:Preety,LastName:Kakkar,Phone:2225556669,Email:preety@test.com}]
    at org.testng.internal.reflect.DataProviderMethodMatcher.getConformingArguments(DataProviderMethodMatcher.java:45)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.injectParameters(Parameters.java:796)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:983)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I remember that I got the same issue before when I tried to convert the object[][] array data into String. If you will see at the second line, I am using Object as a parameter type. I have tested the below code and it is working fine. May be you can do some modifications in it and use it in your project.

```
 @Test( dataProvider = "data" )
        public void test(Object key, Object data)
        {
            System.out.println( "Key: " + key);
            System.out.println( "Data: " + data );
        }


        @DataProvider( name = "data" )
        public Object[][] getData()
        {

            JSONParser parser = new org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser();
            Map<String, JSONObject> dataMap = new HashMap<String, JSONObject>();
            Iterator entriesIterator = null;
            try 
            {
                JSONObject contentObj = (JSONObject)parser.parse(new FileReader(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/test/resources/json/data.json")));
                JSONObject dataObj = (JSONObject)contentObj.get("SuperParent");


                dataObj.keySet().forEach(key -> {
                    dataMap.put(String.valueOf(key), (JSONObject) dataObj.get(key));
                });

                Set entries = dataObj.entrySet();
                 entriesIterator = entries.iterator();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            Object[][] arr = new Object[dataMap.size()][2];
            int i = 0;
            while(entriesIterator.hasNext()){

                Map.Entry mapping = (Map.Entry) entriesIterator.next();

                arr[i][0] = mapping.getKey();
                arr[i][1] = mapping.getValue();

                i++;

            }

            return arr;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Rapper AB. You made my day. Its working :)

Comment: No problem my friend just upvote it then. On the left hand side you can see the arrow up :)

Comment: Hi @UnknownBeast, I tried with another JSON data, it is showing as `Test ignored`. But when i tried with the above data, it is working fine. 
```
     {
      “QASquad": [
        {
          "comment": "TEST_COMMENT",
          "status": “Done",
          "timestamp": "1636659428315L",
          "user": "TEST_USER1"
        },
        {
          "comment": "TEST_COMMENT",
          "status": “WIP",
          "timestamp": "1636659428315L",
          "user": "TEST_USER1"
        }
      ]
    }
```